# Filtering a dataframe (where 1 specific column is type 'object') based on the columns element number length (Association Rule Analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, return, data-science

I have a dataset with a column labeled 'antecedents', that involves a list of elements in it, that are of type 'object', listed like shown below.  How can I filter my dataset to return only rows where that specific antecedent column's element number length is 1? The values

antecedent column example:

(APPLE, BANANA)

(APPLE, PEAR)

(APPLE, BANANA, PEAR)

(APPLE)

I am doing association rule analysis and would only like the rows with 1 antecedent (so APPLE in the case above), and so far I have:

df[df['antecedents'] *now check the length of this object list of elements in the antecedents column and only return rows where this antecedent column's length is 1*

I am unsure what to do to access inside this antecedent column to only return rows whose length is 1 (only one element in the antecedent column).

Comment: Are the antecedents encoded as strings?

Comment: it says they are of type 'object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `.apply()` function.

```py
def antecedent_length(s):
    # Calculate the length of the antecedent
    # `s` is the value in each row
    return len(s)

df[df.antecedents.apply(antecedent_length) == 1]
```

Depending on the exact format of the data, you may need to adjust the function such that it calculates the length properly.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Forgot about apply()!

Comment: Additionally, as a follow up, if I also wanted to create a function that now reads these individual terms in the antecedents column, and measures their string length.., for example:                                                                                                                          
def antecedent_length:                                                                                                                                                         
        return (length of the string for that single element).  I'd be checking the strings length. (>= 3)

Comment: You could make a second function and return `len(s[0])`

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it solves the problem?

Comment: I get an error that reads, 'TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not subscriptable'.  My function is antecedent_string and returns len(s[0]), and my line of code is:  df = df[df.antecedents.apply(antecedent_string) >= 5], but the error above is occurring.

Comment: try ```len(list(s)[0])```. It has to do with the format of your elements. Try testing it out outside of the apply function in order to figure out the syntax you need. Once you can get the length of the object, put that in the return statement.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate your help with this